# XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly error

Tags: mysql, xampp

I tried to run MySQL on XAMPP v3.2.4 - and I get the following error. It did work before.

Log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47143; transaction id 9
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200411 16:11:37
2020-04-11 16:11:37 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

The error:

```
`20:50:47  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:50:47  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:50:47  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:50:47  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:50:47  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:50:47  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
20:50:47  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
`
```

Anyways to fix this? Thanks in advance! OS: W10 Pro 64bit

Comment: Which _error_? There is no error in this log.

Comment: Sorry, forgot. Edited the post.

Comment: Also, the log has been copied after I got the error. Log is: mysql_error.log